# How to implement kiosk mode in an android app?

Tags: android, native, kiosk, kiosk-mode, android-homebutton

I have an android native app in which I want to implement kiosk mode only in single activity. I have tried screen pinning but that works only in lollipop and above. But I want to implement kiosk mode in lower versions also. And I want to exit the kiosk mode on pressing the home button 7 times. Could anyone please help me with that?